statsmodels installed with conda but get ModuleNotFoundError
I am using conda with Spyder on a Windows machine. I would like to use the statsmodels module. I have installed it using conda. But when I run import statsmodels.api as sm in Spyder I get "no module named statsmodels" error.
I don't understand why is it not working. I checked that the package is there using conda list  - it shows it is there, version 0.14.0.
Please explain to me like I am a five year old (I am not computer savvy and I don't have a software background), how to fix this?

It sounds like Spyder is not using the same Python interpreter as the conda environment where you installed statsmodels. After activating that conda environment (or conda activate base if you just used the base environment) what do you get in response to where python ? Then how do you start Spyder, and what do you see in Spyder's preferences under Python interpreter ?

Also, the Spyder FAQs may help you solve this issue.
